# Getting "does not implement 1 interface nor specifies message listener interface" error for non message driven bean

Tags: message-driven-bean

This is my first time posting. Apologies if I have not followed the rules/standards/procedures. The problem I have is the following:

I have the following stateless bean defined:

```
@Stateless(name = "ReportQueueSenderBean", mappedName = "ReportQueueSenderBean")
@EJB(mappedName = "ReportQueueSenderBean", 
        name = "ReportQueueSenderBean", 
        beanInterface = ReportQueueSenderLocal.class, 
        beanName = "ReportQueueSenderBean")
public class ReportQueueSenderBean implements ReportQueueSender, ReportQueueSenderRemote, 
ReportQueueSenderLocal
{
    etc
}
```

The interfaces for the above bean are defined as follows:

```
public interface ReportQueueSender
{
    void addToQueue(ReportRequest repRequest, String clientid) throws Exception;
    int determineNumMessagesInQueue() throws JMSException;
}

@Remote
public interface ReportQueueSenderRemote extends ReportQueueSender
{
 //Marker interface
}

@Local
public interface ReportQueueSenderLocal extends ReportQueueSender
{
  //Marker interface
}
```

And then I have the following message driven bean implemented:

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = 
    "queue/OnlineReportingEngineQueue"), 
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = 
    "javax.jms.Queue")
})
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public class ReportQueueReceiverBean implements MessageListener
{
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message)
    { 
      etc.
    }
   etc.
}
```

I get the following error at deployment time:

> Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEJB0094: EJB 3.1 FR 5.4.2 MessageDrivenBean xxxxx.ReportQueueSenderBean does not implement 1 interface nor specifies message listener interface
> at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.getMessageListenerInterface(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:193)
> at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.processMessageBeans(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:154)
> at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.processAnnotations(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:83)
> at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.processAnnotations(AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:50)
> at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.deploy(AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:76)
> at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:176)
> ... 8 more

The strange thing though is that ReportQueueSenderBean is not defined as a message driven bean but we get the "MessageDrivenBean xxxxx.ReportQueueSenderBean does not implement 1 interface nor specifies message listener interface" error. Any ideas please?

I'm using jboss version:
Release: 10.0.3.Final
Product: WildFly Full 18.0.1.Final

using ejb specification 3.1 I believe.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Vick.

Additional info:

- Both the ReportQueueSenderBean and the ReportQueueReceiverBean classes are in the same package and are part of the same jar file. Same for the ReportQueueSender and the ReportQueueSenderRemote and ReportQueueSenderLocal interfaces.
- There is no entry in the ejb descriptor which describes ReportQueueSenderBean as a message driven bean.